# Inequalityconstraints in the Optimx/Optim R packages

Tags: r, optimization

Can `Optim` or `Optimx` take inequality constraints in a non-linear optimization problem?

I have a nonlinear problem in which there are two types of constraints to be imposed:

- Variables >= 0
- Sum of variables <= 1

Comment: You might want to check out the [CRAN task view for optimization](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

Comment: Optim/optimx is for unconstrained and box-constrained problems only. You seem to have `linear` constraints only (you mention non-linear constraints but the ones you show are bounds and a linear constraint). The `see also` section of `optim` mentions `constrOptim` which allows linear inequality constraints, which is what you have. There are also many other solvers available under R that handle linear and even nonlinear constraints.

Comment: Your constraints: variables <= 0; and sum(variables) <= 1 seem perfectly linear to me...  Also, if none of the variables > 0, then the sum should be <= 0 as well...

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.  maxLik can do inequality constraints, at least some estimators there can do.  If you tell a bit more I can give you the code example.

Comment: @OttToomet: I updated the title and question. I have a non-linear problem with inequality constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with maxLik.  The inequality constraints there must be specified as $Ax + B > 0$ where x is the parameter.

For example, assume you have two parameters and you maximize the exponential hat:

```
f <- function(x) exp( - (x[1]-2)^2 - (x[2]-2)^2)
A <- matrix(c(1,1,-1,-1), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
B <- c(0,1)
```

You can check that now $Ax + B > 0$ is equivalent to your inequality conditions (well, except that you wrote >= instead of > but that does not really matter for numerical solutions).

You can use BFGS or other optimizers.  You need the list of ineqA and ineqB for the constraints:

```
a <- maxBFGS(f, start=c(0.2, 0.2), constraints=list(ineqA=A, ineqB=B))
summary(a)

--------------------------------------------
BFGS maximization 
Number of iterations: 50 
Return code: 0 
successful convergence  
Function value: 0.01104892 
Estimates:
      estimate   gradient
[1,] 0.4990966 0.03316674
[2,] 0.4990966 0.03316674

Constrained optimization based on constrOptim 
1  outer iterations, barrier value -0.0003790423 
--------------------------------------------
```

As you see the constraints are binding, the unconstrained maximum would be at (2,2).

Comment: Sorry, now I answered the question "how to estimate inequality constraints in R", not "do optimx/optim do inequality constraints".

Answer (score 0):

Using L-BFGS-B in `optimx`,

- For Variables >= 0 , you would set the `lower` argument in `optimx` to `rep.int(0, n_variables)`
- For Sum(variables) <= 1, I don't know of a direct way to program this in with `optimx`. I would suggest `upper = rep.int(1, n_variables)`, modifying your objective function to include: if Sum(variables) > 1, objectiveValue = objectiveFunction + large penalty, and then set a starting point that meets all your criteria Vars >=0, Sum(Vars) <=1, (and Vars <=1 as implied by your constraints)